# Best Methods for removing chloramine

Tags: water

I have been looking into this for sometime, and I can't seem to find any definitive answers.

So far I'm pretty convinced that I won't find a reasonable home filter that will eliminate chloramine.

My current method is to carbon filter the water, and then add campden to break down the chloramine.

Anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you've hit on the best way to handle it on a homebrew scale. Half a tablet of campden works for 5 gallons of water so this should be a reasonably cheap and effective method of dealing with the Chloramine.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I do. (i.e. use campden)  I have never noticed off-flavors from chlorine/chloramine.  Filtering the water is a good idea for other reasons, but I find it to be too much trouble.  As long as the alkalinity is appropriate for the beer style, I use campden-treated tap water.  If the alkalinity is too high, I'll mix it with R.O. water purchased at the grocery store.

Comment: How long do you let the campden sit before heating/doughing/brewing